# debug java program step by step in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to debug the whole flow of a java program line by line and I am using eclipse 
how can I do that?

Comment: There's a "debug as" option right next to the "run as". It's pretty obvious.

Comment: Read this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: How are you running your java application? Kayaman is right that there is a debugging option but the config will vary greatly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple steps required to debug a java program in eclipse such as:

1. Setting breakpoints
2. Starting the debugger
3. controlling the program execution. **For line by line use F6 and F5 to step into a method**
4. Evaluating variables etc

Putting everthing here will make the answer too long. I advice you to follow this tutorial :

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 5):

Create a break point in the first line of your main method then using F5 (step into) to walk through it.

BTW, such questions are all over the web. To be a good programmer, use google wisely.

Answer (score 2):

- Set the breakpoints in all the method which you want to debug
- F3 can be used to navigate into the method
- Then start the debugging
- Press F5