# Why is this method not working?

Tags: java, arrays

I made this method(interleave) that takes 3 arrays as input and then returns an array which has the elements of each array in order. If there in no element present in an array, then "-" is added t the final array.

Example: if these arrays are fed int the method - ["1";"2";"3"], ["4"], ["5";"6"] then it will return this array -

["1"; "4"; "5"; "2"; "-"; "6"; "3"; "-"; "-"]

But, when I am calling this I am getting nothing as an output.

```
static String[] interleave(String[] xs, String[] ys, String[] zs) {


    int length1 = xs.length;
    int length2 = ys.length;
    int length3 = zs.length;
    int larLength = 0;

    if (((length1 > length2) && (length2 > length3) || ((length1 > length3) && (length3 > length2)))) {

        larLength = length1;
    }

    else if (((length2 > length1) && (length1 > length3) || ((length1 > length3) && (length3 > length2)))) {

        larLength = length2;
    }

    else if ((length3 > length2) && (length2 > length1)) {

        larLength = length3;
    }

    String[] result = new String[larLength*larLength];

    for(int i = 0; i < (larLength*larLength - 1); i++) {

        if (xs[i] != null) {result[i] = xs[i];}
        else {result[i] = "-";}
        if (ys[i] != null) {result[i+1] = ys[i];}
        else {result[i+1] = "-";}
        if (zs[i] != null) {result[i+2] = zs[i];}
        else {result[i+2] = "-";}
    }



    return result;

}
```

Comment: The length calculation seems super-difficult. Should be just `3 * max(length1, length2, length3)`

Comment: You assigning to the following elements of `result` in this order: 0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,...

Comment: most IDE's offer a debug mode where you can place breakpoints, and step through the code to see what it's doing http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-debug-launch.htm or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977397/debug-java-program-step-by-step-in-eclipse

Comment: Problem is in your loop, you will get array index out of bound exception. See the loop in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the first part of the code with a simple `Math.max(length1,length2,length3)`

Here what you actually need is number of arrays * larLength

```
String[] result = new String[3*larLength];
```

And finally you need to fix the position at which you add the elements in your result array. It is not `i`, `i+1` and `i+2`.

Instead the correct positions are:

first position to instert at :`resultIndex = i*3`,

second position : `resultIndex+1`

third position : `resultIndex+2`

So your code would look like this:

```
String[] result = new String[3*larLength];

for(int i = 0; i < (larLength - 1); i++) {
    int  resultIndex = i*3;
    if (xs[i] != null) {result[resultIndex] = xs[i];}
    else {result[i] = "-";}
    if (ys[i] != null) {result[resultIndex+1] = ys[i];}
    else {result[i+1] = "-";}
    if (zs[i] != null) {result[resultIndex+2] = zs[i];}
    else {result[i+2] = "-";}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dummy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xs[] = {"1", "2", "3"}, ys[] = {"4"} , zs[] = {"5", "6"};
    int larLength = Math.max(Math.max(xs.length, ys.length), 
            Math.max(ys.length, zs.length));
    int ind = 0;
    String res[] = new String[3*larLength];
    for (int i=0;i<larLength;i++) {
        if (i<xs.length) res[ind++] = xs[i];
        else res[ind++] = "-";
        if (i<ys.length) res[ind++] = ys[i];
        else res[ind++] = "-";
        if (i<zs.length) res[ind++] = zs[i];
        else res[ind++] = "-";
    }

    for (int i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(res[i]);
    }
}
```