# how to count the number of letters in an array java

Tags: java

I have an assignment about how to count the number of letters in an array. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class task1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




            //Create a scanner object 
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Prompt user's input
            System.out.println("Enter strings (use a space to separate them; hit enter to finish) : ");

            String str = input.nextLine();

            // use split to divide the string into different words cutting by " "
            String [] wordsArray = str.trim().split(" ");

            System.out.println("The length of string is " + wordsArray.length);




            for(int i = 0 ; i < wordsArray.length; i++){


                char [] eachLetterinArray =  wordsArray[i].toCharArray();


                    for(int j = 0,count = 0 ; j < eachLetterinArray.length; j++){

                        if(    (eachLetterinArray[j]+'a'-97 >=65 && eachLetterinArray[j]+'a'-97 <=90 )
                            || (eachLetterinArray[j]+'a'-97 >=97 && eachLetterinArray[j]+'a'-97 <=122 )  ){

                            count++;

                        }

                        System.out.print(count);
                    }





            }
}
```

if I enter "end tr" 
the output is "12312"
but what I want is "3 and 2 "

I have tried a lot and still have nothing to do about this...
can you help me?

Comment: `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` seems IDE generated for you. Try debugger in IDE

Comment: But I am new in java.. I don't know how to try debugger in IDE..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977397/debug-java-program-step-by-step-in-eclipse

Comment: You are printing inside your loop. put `System.out.print(count);` two lines below and it will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print `count` per word, but you are printing for each character.  Just print the `count` variable outside of the inner loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
    char[] eachLetterinArray = wordsArray[i].toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < eachLetterinArray.length; j++) {
        if ((eachLetterinArray[j] + 'a' - 97 >= 65 && eachLetterinArray[j] + 'a' - 97 <= 90)
                || (eachLetterinArray[j] + 'a' - 97 >= 97 && eachLetterinArray[j] + 'a' - 97 <= 122)) {

            count++;
        }                
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

**Improvement:**

Instead of the little bit complex condition, you can do this way also:

```
if (Character.isLetter(eachLetterinArray[j])) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: but count can not be put outside the inner loop because I create the count in the inner loop ...

Comment: I got it ! that's amazing ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are using `space` to split the word and count the letters. So use `split()` on string.

`split()` takes a string which splits the word. In your case it is space.

It returns splitted strings as an array. Just iterate over strings and use `length()` on string to get the number of characters present in the word.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int count;
        String s = "This is your string for example";
        String[] split = s.split(" ");
        for(String str: split)
        {
            char[] ch = str.toCharArray();   // convert string to char array
            count = 0;                       // reset count for every new word/string
            for(char c: ch)                  // iterate over all the characters
            {
                if(Character.isLetter(c))    // Returns true if the character is a Letter
                {
                    count++;                 // increase the count to represent no. of letters
                }
        }
        System.out.print(count + " ");       // print the no.of characters that are letters in a word/string.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but what if the user's input is "as3"

Comment: the output is 3.. but I want it is 2 since it only has 2 letters

Answer (score 0):

```
int countedLength = 0;

for(String string: arrayList) {
countedLength += string.length();
}

//Your count of Number of Letters in Array
System.out.pritnln(countedLength);
```

Or if you want to count every letter unique, do a new for in this for like

```
if(letter.equals("a")) {
letterVariableCountA++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, you were printing your count within the loop which is why it was counting. If you set the inital count value outside of it, you can then print it once the loop is complete, and then set it back to 0 before it starts on the next word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "test1 phrase";
    int count = 0;

    // use split to divide the string into different words cutting by " "
    String[] wordsArray = str.trim().split(" ");

    System.out.println("The length of string is " + wordsArray.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {


        char[] eachLetterinArray = wordsArray[i].toCharArray();


        for (int j = 0; j < eachLetterinArray.length; j++) {

            if ((eachLetterinArray[j] + 'a' - 97 >= 65 && eachLetterinArray[j] + 'a' - 97 <= 90)
                    || (eachLetterinArray[j] + 'a' - 97 >= 97 && eachLetterinArray[j] + 'a' - 97 <= 122)) {

                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(count + "\n");
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

with the above example I got an output of

```
The length of string is 2
4
6
```