# Java won't print output

Tags: java

I'm using binary search to write a simple square root calculator that takes in doubles in Java. When I tried to test my code by printing out the answer in the main function, however, nothing got printed out in the terminal. I also got errors `Possible lossy conversion from double to float`......
Here is my code:

```
public class MyMath{
    public static double sqrt(double n){
        double u = 1;
        double l = 0;
        float m = (u + l) / 2;
        double norm_input = 1;
        float acc = 0.00000000001;
        double answer = 0;
        if ((n > 0) && (n < 1)){
            if ((m * m) < n){
                l = m;
            }else{
                u = m;
            }
            answer = (u + l) / 2;
            return answer;
        }else{
            int count = 0;
            while (n > 1){
                n = n / 4;
                norm_input = norm_input * 2;
                count++;
            }
            while ((u - l) > acc){
                if ((m * m) < n){
                    l = m;
                }else{
                    u = m;
                }
            }
            answer = (u + l) / 2 * norm_input;
            return answer;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double a = new MyMath().sqrt(4);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are `m` and `acc` `float`s? Better names may also help to increase the readability. I guess that your while loop does not terminate. Btw: you know `Math.sqrt` already?

Comment: try using only one type for the beginning and debug your code around the second while-loop.

Comment: Definitely an endless loop. You should learn to use the debugger of your IDE. Small tip `while ((u - l) > acc)` is problematic as `u` and `l` never actually change their values.

Comment: m is the midpoint between upperbound and lowerbound, and acc is accuracy for better approximation. I know `Math.sqrt` but I can't use it for the assignment...

Comment: while ((u - l) > acc) is infinite loop.. In loop l=m condition where both have same value .5 so value of 'l' not change.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977397/debug-java-program-step-by-step-in-eclipse

Comment: BTW, is there anyway to debug java in Xcode?

Comment: By the way, your method is static, so you don't need to create a new class; just do `MyMath.sqrt(4)`.

Answer (score 3):

It is stuck in infinite loop in second while condition, that's the reason it is not printing values to console.

Answer (score 1):

`float m = (u + l) / 2;`
Here you have to type cast into float because when two datatype variable participated in division the result would be in higher data type.

`float acc = 0.00000000001;`
Here also  you have type cast because by default java treats a decimal point value as Double.

```
while ((u - l) > acc){
    if ((m * m) < n){
        l = m;
    }
}
```

and your code here is going to infinite loop .