# Sort array using if condition in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Below program is in java which is suppose to sort array elements in ascending order but it is not functioning as such. Please try out the program below and explain me why it is not storing some of the values in 'second' array. Some values in second array is stored as 0. Which I couldn't able to figure. Kindly solve this program and let me know. Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first[]={9,8,2,6,3};
    int second[]=new int[5];
    for(int i=0;i<first.length;i++){
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<second.length;j++){
            if(first[i]<first[j]){
                count++;
            }
        }      
        if(count == 0){
            second[4]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 1){
            second[3]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 2){
            second[2]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 3){
            second[1]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 4){
            second[0]=first[i];
        }
        System.out.print(second[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to sort a int array. Is there a reason, why you don't use Arrays.sort()?

Comment: do you know how to debug Naveen??

Comment: And if you want to sort an array without using Arrays.sort() why don't you look up sorting algorithms like mergesort, quicksort or even bubblesort?

Comment: I may not be well informed, but is that even a valid sorting algorithm ?

Comment: Your Problem is, that you override values in `second`. Because `count` can be the same value several time. This can be easily found with debugging. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977397/debug-java-program-step-by-step-in-eclipse

Comment: @GAlexMES I just want to try without sort() method.

Comment: Add an answer, accept and close this.

Comment: Or just delete this question. This has no value whatsoever.

Comment: `code` 
        for(int a:second){
            System.out.println(a);

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that will do what you asked for:

```
public class SortIt{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {9,8,2,6,3};
        boolean a = true;
        int index = 0;
        int arrBuffer;
        int check = 0;
        while(a){
            if(index + 1 != arr.length){
                if(arr[index] > arr[index+1]){
                    arrBuffer = arr[index+1];
                    arr[index+1] = arr[index];
                    arr[index] = arrBuffer;
                    index += 1;
                    check = 0;
                }
                else if(arr[index] <= arr[index+1]){
                    index += 1;
                    check += 1;
                }
                if(check == arr.length){a = false;}
            }
            else
                index = 0;
        }
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i = 0; i + 1 < arr.length; i++){
            System.out.print("'" + arr[i] + "', " );
        }
        System.out.println("'" + arr[arr.length-1] + "']");
    }
}
```

Input:

```
9,8,2,6,3
```

Output:

```
['2', '3', '6', '8', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first[]={9,8,2,6,3};
    int second[]=new int[5];
    for(int i=0;i<first.length;i++){
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<second.length;j++){
            if(first[i]<first[j]){
                count++;
            }
        }      
        if(count == 0){
            second[4]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 1){
            second[3]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 2){
            second[2]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 3){
            second[1]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 4){
            second[0]=first[i];
        }
        //System.out.print(second[i]);
    }
    for(int a:second){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are printing array inside the loop that's why some values are printed as zeros.Her is the modified code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first[]={9,8,2,6,3};
    int second[]=new int[5];
    for(int i=0;i<first.length;i++){
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<second.length;j++){
            if(first[i]<first[j]){
                count++;
            }
        }      
        if(count == 0){
            second[4]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 1){
            second[3]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 2){
            second[2]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 3){
            second[1]=first[i];
        }
        if(count == 4){
            second[0]=first[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(second));
}
```