# Why platformer collision works great on one platform, but barely works with platform array?

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I have read all the suggested topics. I want to create collisions for platformer game with C#, .NET Gatgeteer, .NETMF 4.3 on VS 2013. I started with one platform and after some time collisions on it worked nicely. I thought that for collisions with many platforms I just needed to put an array of platforms through collision check instead of one platform, but I was wrong. 
I get my platform array from level map which is string array. So far I have encountered these problems:

1) If platform width or height is changed it also changes the platform 
   position and no matter how hard I tried I couldn't find why.

2) If I only put one platform in the map (if there is only one platform in the 
  array), player falls throught the platform and even through the ground.

3) If there is more than one platform, collision works best on last created:

*Top collision works only if at the start of the level, when player is 
   falling down, he falls down only on the platfor that was created last and 
   it works perfectly. You can jump as many times as you want, until you land 
   on the ground. After that the top collision dissapears.

*Sides collision works all the time. The platform that was created last 
    works perfectly. While the player goes inside other platforms a little bit 
    while I'm holding the joystic, just after I realease the joystick it goes 
    back to the possition where it shoud be when colliding.

I read in the Stackoverflow article "C# Platform Collisions Not Working With Multiple Platforms" that if collision detected, the loop should be broken. I heve tried a few variations of it: for, foreach, while with bool, but all of them made game lag awfully (foreach lags even without break). Using brake should do quite an opposite of slowing down the game.

4) Collisions work only in the groud map level (map[11]).

Thank you four your time, I would highly appreciate an answer to any of my questions.

------------------------------------------------------------CODE-------------------------------------------------------------
This part is responsible for platforms map and array. Collisions work only in ground level (map[11]).

```
     //Map generation
     // -88 this offset makes the platform align with botom of the screen
     int basePositionTop = -88;
     int basePositionLeft = 0;
     int platformId = 0;
     int playerHeight = 30;
     int playerWidth = 30;
     Platform[] platformMap = new Platform[200];   

            void SetupUI()
            {
                // initialize window
                mainWindow = displayT43.WPFWindow; 

                // setup the layout
                layout = new Canvas();
                Border background = new Border();
                background.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                background.Height = 272;
                background.Width = 480;

                layout.Children.Add(background);
                Canvas.SetLeft(background, 0);
                Canvas.SetTop(background, 0);

                //add the player
                player = new Rectangle(playerWidth, playerHeight);
                player.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                layout.Children.Add(player);

                // Platformer map
                string[] map = new string[12];
                map[0] =  ".....................................";
                map[1] =  ".....................................";
                map[2] =  ".....................................";
                map[3] =  ".....................................";
                map[4] =  ".....................................";
                map[5] =  ".....................................";
                map[6] =  ".....................................";
                map[7] =  ".....................................";
                map[8] =  ".....................................";
                map[9] =  ".....................................";
                map[10] = ".....................................";
                map[11] = ".....#..#............................";


                for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < map[i].Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (map[i][j] == '#')
                        {
                            platformMap[platformId] = new Platform(platWidth, platHeight);
                            platformMap[platformId].set(basePositionLeft + j * platWidth , basePositionTop + i * platHeight);
                            platformId++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Adding platforms to screen
                for (int i = 0; i < platformId; i++)
                {               
                    layout.Children.Add(platformMap[i].get());
                }

                mainWindow.Child = layout;
            }
```

This part is reponsible for collision detection as well as for actions when top or bottom collision is detected.

```
    int power; 
    int jumpPower = 36;
    bool jumped = true;
    int playerTopPosition; 
    int playerLeftPosition = 250;                       

 void jumpTimer_Tick(GT.Timer timer)
 {
    double y = joystick.GetPosition().Y;

     //Jump part
     if (!jumped) // if didn't jump
     {
       if (y >= 0.7) // and jumps
       {
          jumped = true;
          power = jumpPower;
       }
     }

     //Jump
     if (jumped)
     {
         playerTopPosition -= power;
         power -= 8;
     }

     // update player top position
     Canvas.SetTop(player, playerTopPosition);

  // Platform check loop                            
  for (int i = 0; i < platformId; i++)
  {

   //TOP AND BOTTOM COLLISION
   //Check if player is in platform bounds x axis
   if ((playerLeftPosition + playerWidth) >= platformMap[i].posLeft() 
                    && playerLeftPosition <= platformMap[i].posLeft() + platWidth) 
   {
    //TOP collision. (platHeight/2 -1) - even if player is in platform 
    // (from top) and doesn't touch the middle he is set on top 
    if (playerTopPosition + playerHeight >= platformMap[i].posTop() 
    && playerTopPosition + playerHeight <= platformMap[i].posTop() + (platHeight / 2 - 1))

    {
       playerTopPosition = platformMap[i].posTop() - playerHeight;
       jumped = false;                                        
    }

    //BOTTOM collision. (platHeight/2 + 1) - even if player is in platform 
    //(from bottom) and don't touch the middle he collides with bottom 
    if (playerTopPosition <= platformMap[i].posTop() + platHeight 
     && playerTopPosition >= platformMap[i].posTop() + (platHeight / 2 + 1))
    {
           playerTopPosition = platformMap[i].posTop() + platHeight;
           power = -1;// without this player gets stuck on platform bottom
    }
   }      
     else jumped = true; // if player steps off platform - he falls


    // the very bottom collision
    if (playerTopPosition + playerHeight >= displayT43.Height) 
    {
       playerTopPosition = displayT43.Height - playerHeight;
       jumped = false;
    }

    //SIDES COLLISION
    //Check if player is in platform bounds y axis
    if (playerTopPosition + playerHeight <= platformMap[i].posTop() + platHeight 
     && playerTopPosition >= platformMap[i].posTop())
    {
     //RIGHT collision. (platWidth / 2 - 1) - even if player is in platform 
     // (from left) and don't touch the middle he collides with left
     if ((playerLeftPosition + playerWidth) + 1 >= platformMap[i].posLeft() 
      && (playerLeftPosition + playerWidth) <= platformMap[i].posLeft() + (platWidth/2-1))
     {
        playerLeftPosition = platformMap[i].posLeft() - playerWidth;
        stopRight = true;// stops moving right
     }
       else stopRight = false;

     //LEFT collision. (platWidth / 2 - 1) - even if player is in platform 
     // (from right) and don't touch the middle he collides with right
     if (playerLeftPosition - 1 <= platformMap[i].posLeft() + platWidth 
          && playerLeftPosition >= platformMap[i].posLeft() + (platWidth / 2 + 1))
     {
        playerLeftPosition = platformMap[i].posLeft() + platWidth;
        stopLeft = true;// stops moving left
     }
       else stopLeft = false;

    }
      else
      {
         stopRight = false;
         stopLeft = false;               
      }

     // update player top position                          
     Canvas.SetTop(player, playerTopPosition); 
  }

 }
```

This is responsible for left/rigth movements and actions when left or right collision is detected.

```
     bool stopLeft = false;// makes stop move left
     bool stopRight = false;// makes stop move right


     void JoystickTimer_Tick(GT.Timer timer)
     {
                double x = joystick.GetPosition().X; // joystic x scale [-1;1]
                // move left
                if (x < -0.3 && playerLeftPosition > 0 && !stopLeft)
                {
                    playerLeftPosition -= 5;
                }
                // move right
                else if (x > 0.7 && playerLeftPosition < displayT43.Width - playerWidth 
                                                                         && !stopRight)
                {
                    playerLeftPosition += 5;
                }

                Canvas.SetLeft(player, playerLeftPosition);// update player left postion
    }
```

Class Platform.cs

```
    class Platform
    {
           private Rectangle platformRectangle { get; set; }

            int left = 0;
            int top = 0;

           public Platform()
           { 
           }

           public Platform(int Width, int Height)
           {
               this.platformRectangle = new Rectangle();
               this.platformRectangle.Height = Height;
               this.platformRectangle.Width = Width;

               platformRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
           }
           public void set(int leftPosition, int topPosition)
           {
               Canvas.SetLeft(platformRectangle, leftPosition);
               Canvas.SetTop(platformRectangle, topPosition);
               this.left = leftPosition;
               this.top = topPosition;
           }

           public Rectangle get()
           {
               return platformRectangle;
           }
           public int posLeft()
           {
               return left;
           }
           public int posTop()
           {
               return top;
           }
   }
```

Comment: This way too much code for us to look into.

Comment: TaW, thank you. I tried make it more readable.

Comment: But I don't know how to deal with margins.

Comment: @PauliusJacikevičius Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of the question. Check the [help/on-topic] on what questions you can ask on Stack Overflow. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You might want to debug your application, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977397/debug-java-program-step-by-step-in-eclipse.

Comment: You shouldn't try to move the player when there is a collision (that may cause another collision). Instead, if the player moves, check if the movement target would cause a collision. You can use standard rectangle collision code for that. (google for rectangle overlap). If the movetarget causes a collision, don't update the player's coordinates. But in your case the problem seems to be in how you create and loop through your platforms, so that's actually a separate problem. Start by creating a for loop that accurately lists all platforms. If that fails, create a separate question for that.