# Why isn't the contains method I created comparing my objects?

Tags: java, list

The contains method I built for implementing a List never returns true. It is almost as if it isn't comparing the object I passed to it to the objects already in the list. I am wondering if the .equals method I am using may be the issue. The class variables are: private T[] list and private int entries.

I have tried casting to Object hoping that a more generic type might be easier for the equals method to use. I have even tried to directly compare objects using == to no avail.

```
public class MyList<T> implements MyCollectionInterface<T> 
{

private T[] list;
private int entries;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 25;
private static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 100000;
private boolean integrityOK;

//***************************************************************

public MyList()
{

  this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);

}

//********************************************************************

public MyList(int capacity)
{

  integrityOK = false;

  if(capacity < DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
  {
     capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
  }
  else
  {
     checkCapacity(capacity);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Suppress an un-checked cast warning 
  from the compiler
                                 // cast is safe because the new array 
  contains null entries
  T[] tempList = (T[])new Object[capacity];
  list = tempList;
  entries = 0;
  integrityOK = true;

}

//**************************************************************************  
/**
* Adds a new entry to this collection
* @param newItem The object to be added to the collection
* @return True if the addition is successful, or false if not.
*/
public boolean add(T newItem) 
{
     boolean result = false;
     if(isArrayFull())
     {
        ensureCapacity();
     }

     if(newItem != null)
     {
        list[entries + 1] = newItem;
        entries++;
        result = true;      
     }
     else
     {
        result = false;
     }

     return result;
 }// End add

 //*******************************************************************

 public T remove()
 {

  checkIntegrity();
  T result = null;

  if(entries > 0)
  {

     result = list[entries];
     list[entries] = null; // Setting this to null flags it for removal and prevents malicious code from accessing it
     entries--;

  }
  return result;

 }


 //********************************************************************
 /**
* Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this collection.
* @param anEntry The entry to be removed.
* @return True if the removal was successful, or false if not.
*/
public boolean remove(T anEntry)
{

  checkIntegrity();
  boolean result = false;

  for(int i = 1; i <= entries; i++)
  {
     if(list[i].equals(anEntry))
     {
        list[i] = null;
        removeGap(i);
        entries--;
        result = true;          
     }
  }
  return result;

} // End remove
//**********************************************************************
/**
* Removes all entries from this collection.
*/
public void clear()
{
  while(!isEmpty())
  {

     remove();

  }
}
//**********************************************************************
/**
* Gets the current number of entries in this collection.
*
* @return The integer number of entries currently in the collection.
*/
public int getCurrentSize()
{
  return entries;
}
//***********************************************************************   
/**
* Check to see if the collection is empty.
* @return True if the collection is empty, or false if not.
*/
public boolean isEmpty() {
  return entries == 0;
} // End isEmpty
//**********************************************************************
/**
* Counts the number of times a given entry appears in this collection.
* @param anEntry The entry to be counted.
* @return The number of times anEntry appears in the collection.
*/
public int getFrequencyOf(T anEntry)
{

  checkIntegrity();
  int frequency = 0;

  for(int index = 1; index < entries; index++) 
  {

     if (anEntry.equals(list[index]))
     {

        frequency++;

     }// End if

  }// End for

  return frequency;

}

//********************************************************************  
/**
* Tests whether this collection contains a given entry.
* @param anEntry The entry to locate.
* @return True if the collection contains anEntry, or false if not.
*/
public boolean contains(T anEntry)
{
  checkIntegrity();
  boolean found = false;

  for (int index = 1; index <= entries; index++)
  {
      T result = list[index];

      if(anEntry == result)
      {

        found = true;

      }       
  }
  return found;
} // End contains

//***********************************************************************

/**
* Retrieves all entries that are in this collection.
* @return A newly allocated array of all the entries in the collection. 
* Note: If the collection is empty, the returned array is empty.
*/
public Object[] toArray() 
{

  Object[] anArray = new Object[entries];

  for (int index = 0; index <= anArray.length; index++) 
  {

     anArray[index] = list[index + 1];

  } // End for
  return  anArray;

} // End toArray

//************************************************************************

public T getEntry(int position)
{

  if(position < 1 || position > entries)
  {

    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Position is out of bounds for the 
    list.");

  }
  T entry = null;
  entry = list[position];
  return entry;
}


//*****************************************************************

private void checkIntegrity()
{

  if(!integrityOK)
  {

     throw new SecurityException("List object is corrupt.");

  }

}// End checkIntegrity

//********************************************************************

private boolean isArrayFull()
{
  return entries >= list.length;
}

//************************************************************************

private void ensureCapacity()
{

  int capacity = list.length;

  if(entries >= capacity)
  {

     int newCapacity = 2 * capacity;
     checkCapacity(newCapacity);
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Suppress an un-checked cast warning from the compiler - cast is safe because the new array contains null entries
     T[] tempList = (T[])new Object[newCapacity];
     for(int i = 1; i <= entries; i++)
     {

        tempList[i] = list[i];

     }

     list = tempList;

  }

}

//************************************************************************

private void checkCapacity(int capacity)
{

  if(capacity >= MAX_CAPACITY)
  {

     throw new IllegalStateException("Attempted to create a list that exceeded max capacity.");

  }

}

//************************************************************************

private void removeGap(int givenPosition)
{

  int removedIndex = givenPosition;
  for (int index = removedIndex; index < entries; index++)
  {
     list[index] = list[index + 1];
  }

} // end removeGap

//***********************************************************************

private void makeRoom(int givenPosition)
{

  int newIndex = givenPosition;
  int lastIndex = entries;

  for (int index = lastIndex; index >= newIndex; index--)
  {

     list[index + 1] = list[index];

  }

}  //end makeRoom

} // End class
```

The method should return true if anEntry is in the list, yet it never does. It is always returns false.

Comment: Off topic but if equals returns true then return true directly from the method, no point in looping through the rest of the list if you have already found an object.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Btw.: Your loop start at index `1`, but should start at index `0`.

Comment: You should use the debugger of your IDE to check what is going on in your methods when they are called. Depending on the IDE you are using you might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977397/debug-java-program-step-by-step-in-eclipse. And you should check why you sometimes start at index `1` and sometimes at index `0`.