# Why is the non-zero return int acting as 0?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I was tracing this and always found the last answer to be 103 but when I run the program, it's 13. The return value is not getting added to t.sum in `methodThree`.

I've tried modifying the line to

```java
t.sum += methodTwo() + 7;
```

But the answer is the same. The value of t.sum is 12 before and after executing this line. Why is the value of t.sum unchanged in this line?

```java
class Test {

    int x = 2;
    int y = 4;
    int sum = 6;
    Test t;

    void methodOne() {
        t = new Test();
        t.sum += sum;
        System.out.println(t.sum);
    }

    int methodTwo() {
        System.out.println(++x);
        methodOne();
        System.out.println(y++);
        return x * y * sum;
    }

    int methodThree() {
        t.sum += methodTwo();
        System.out.println(++t.sum);
        return --sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.methodOne();
        Test t2 = new Test();
        t2.methodOne();
        t2.methodThree();

    }

}
```

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to use your debugger to step through the program.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977397/debug-java-program-step-by-step-in-eclipse

Comment: Are you sure you're following which variables you're altering on `t`, which on `t2`  and which you're altering on `this`? Because it's not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: The first line of `methodOne` is `t = new Test();` so you always throw away the current `t` on every invocation of `methodOne`. Why does `Test` **contain** an instance of `Test`?

Comment: Start by removing `Test t;` from your class.  The Test instances created in the `main` method are the only ones you should be working with.

Comment: @VGR `methodOne` uses the `t` in the class, so we can’t just delete it. Maybe start with renaming one the two variables currently both called `t` to reduce confusion.

Comment: note that `methodOne` (called by `methodTwo`) is creating a new instance and assigning it to `t` - so `t.sum` after call is another value then before (result is added to previous one).... (a nice example of how to **NEVER** write code)

Comment: @OleV.V. I was hoping the next logical step, replacing every t.sum with `this.sum`, would become evident when those compile errors arose.

Comment: you can save the value of `t` before calling `methodTwo` (`Test tmp = t`) and examine its fields after `t.sum += ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it’s tricky. What teases in `methodThree` is that `t` is changed in the course of the call to `methodTwo`. So when you are looking at `t.sum` before and after that call, you are not looking at the same `t`. How is `t` changed? This happens when `methodTwo` calls `methodOne`, which in turn creates a new `Test` object and assigns it to `t`.

We also need to be aware of what the usual left-to-right evaluation means in this case. `t.sum += methodTwo();` is in some sense evaluated left to right, in another sense right to left. What do I mean? Java starts from the left, looks at `t.sum` and from this decides which `sum` to add the method result to: the `sum` in the object that `t` refers to prior to the call. The call returns 90, which is added into the *old*  `t` object. As I said, in the meantime a new `t` object has been created with a `sum` of 12. Therefore `t.sum` is also 12 after the statement has completed.

Comment: adding a bit, JLS [15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) describes the execution order - first 2 steps: "First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable...", "the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated..."