# Integer variable does not update when if condition is true

Tags: java

```
public class test
{
    static Scanner store = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str1 = args[0];
        String str2 = args[1];

        System.out.printf("%nThere are %d dissimilar characters in the two strings.%n", CountNotSim(str1, str2));
    }
    public static int CountNotSim(String str1, String str2)
    {
        String s1 = str1.toLowerCase();
        String s2 = str2.toLowerCase();
        char[] a1 = new char[s1.length()];
        char[] a2 = new char[s2.length()];

        for (int g = 0; g < s1.length(); g++)
            a1[g] = s1.charAt(g);
        for (int h = 0; h < s2.length(); h++)
            a2[h] = s2.charAt(h);

        int check = 0, stored;
        char[] array = new char[26];
        int ctr = s1.length() + s2.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
        {
            check = 0;
            stored = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < a2.length; j++)
            {
                if (a1[i] == a2[j])
                {
                    check++;
                    for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
                    {
                        if (array[k] == ' ')
                            if (stored == 0)
                                array[k] = a1[i];
                        if (a1[i] == array[k])
                        {
                            stored = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print(stored + "/ ");
                }
            }
            if (check > 0)
            {
                if (stored == 0)
                    ctr -= (check + 1);
                else if (stored == 1)
                    ctr--;
            }
            System.out.print(ctr + " "); //checker
        }
        System.out.println();

        return ctr;
    }
}
```

The program checks for dissimilar letters in two strings inputted from the command line. Variable "stored" is supposed to change to 1 whenever there's a match to avoid extra deductions to variable "ctr". However, for some reason, not only does "stored's" value not change, the array "array" also doesn't update its elements whenever there's a match. I'm at a loss on how to fix it--nothing looks incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately it's quite hard to follow what your code is meant to be doing, or where it's going wrong, precisely. What are your inputs? Where exactly do you expect something to happen which isn't happening? Have you debugged through the code?

Comment: have you tryed to use a step-by-step debugger? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977397/debug-java-program-step-by-step-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this:

```
char[] array = new char[26];
...
for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
    {
    if (array[k] == ' ') {
        ...
```

But you simply set the length of `array` not its content.

As a `char` array, it's filled with the default char value, which is not the character space  but the value `0` (**not** the character 0, but the numeric value 0)

So `array[k] == ' '` will never be true.

Try with that:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
    {
    if (array[k] == 0) {
        ...
```